# Не могу добавить запись в БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

Осваиваю возможности работы с базами данных C#. Создал локальную базу данных `Clients` с двумя таблицами `Companies` и `Users`. (клиенты - компании, у которых в свою очередь есть пользователи, но это не суть). Сгенерировал сущностную модель базы данных `Clients` (EDM). При попытке добавления записи в таблицу возникают трудности: код срабатывает без ошибок, однако в самой базе данных изменений не наблюдается. Что я делаю не так?

```
void Test()
{
    ClientsEntities context1 = new ClientsEntities();    
    try
    {
        context1.Companies.Add(
            new Companies {CompanyID = 1, ContractStatus = 2, CompanyName = "ggg"});
        MessageBox.Show("Успешно");
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("fail");
    }
    context1.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: А причём тут WPF к вашему вопросу?

Comment: Ну да, наверное не совсем в тему (а так, создаю приложение WPF)

Comment: Тогда давайте уберём лишний код из вопроса.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос `connectionString`. Как проверяете, что "изменений не наблюдается"?

Comment: После запуска программы и нажатия кнопки (появляется Messagebox успех) открываю базу данных, в ней нет ничего кроме имен столбцов.

Comment: Попробуй "context1.SaveChanges();" перенести за добавлением строки и только потом выводить окно с сообщением.